# How fast is Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am experimenting with GAE for last 2 Months.

I am saving records to the bigtable by uploading CSV file.

My Test File's size is 300 KB.

Here what i found

**Local system**

- Upload take less than 1 second
- Process 2500 records in 3 seconds

**On Google Sandbox**

- Upload takes 5-7 seconds.
- Processing file gives timeout.
- It only save 60-180 records.

My questions are

1. Why it takes too much time?
2. Is there a way to reduce this time?
3. Google counts this processing towards CPU uses. They do not disclose h/w so what CPU internally they use? I mean do i get a CPU euquivalent or greater than PIII?

---

Edited for **@Drew Sears**'s answer.

What i am doing at present

1. Upload the file to GAE
2. Get uploaded data bytes. By stream, count lines , save it into bigtable.
3. There is a unique field, id, my Record.
4. Now, i create queue

int x = linesCount/ 50;

```
for(int i<0;i=x;i++)
{
        x = i * 50;
        Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("test-queue");
        queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.url("/TestQueue")
                .param("id", id.toString())
                .param("startIdx",String.valueOf(x))
                .param("totRec",String.valueOf(50))
        );
    }

int y = linesCount % 50;
if( y > 0 )
{
    x = (linesCount / 50) * 50;
    Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("test-queue");
    queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.url("/TestQueue")
            .param("id", id.toString())
            .param("startIdx",String.valueOf(x))
            .param("totRec",String.valueOf(y))
    );                      
}
```

The task processing servlet read file from storage and using totRec and startIdx process the file and close it..

Comment: Is the time you experience on google sandbox at the first request? What about consequent requests?

Comment: The latency you are experiencing isn't caused by the lack of CPU power, but by Implementation of the GAE datastore (and your network connection). GAE shares resources with other applications on the same servers, but they have plenty of CPU cycles to go around...  It's the datastore that is lagging.

Comment: In first request it save only 60 rceords. Next request improve speed and it save 120-150 records. now maximum goes to 184 records

Comment: OK, so we can save roughly 300 rceords in one requerst (30 second).

Comment: GAE may scale well, but especially batch access (multiple reads and writes) to the data store is incredibly slow and billed with a lot of used CPU time.

Comment: In the code you include, you're enqueuing tasks - what's timing out, enqueuing the tasks, or the tasks themselves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really not a great way to test App Engine's scalability.

1. If it's taking you 7 seconds to post 300KB, the bottleneck is almost certainly your upstream bandwidth, not Google's downstream bandwidth, or anything to do with App Engine. I routinely get much faster upload speeds.
2. If you want requests to finish faster, minimize your RPC calls. Every datastore get, put, or query is a round-trip to an external server. If you're looping over hundreds of rows and doing a put inside each loop iteration, you're incurring a massive amount of unnecessary overhead. Save all of your entities using one datastore put and you will get much faster results. Guido's [AppStats framework](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) is a great tool for finding RPC optimization opportunities.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the perils of doing a separate put() for each row

Comment: I can minimize RPC request but how can i reduce datastore request? I have to save 3k records that need 3k database put (or makePersistant() call in my situation). Is there a bulk save method? s

Comment: Same thing. Each datastore request is an RPC call. Yes, the datastore lets you store multiple entities in one call. In Python this is just db.put() with a list of entities; I don't know what the syntax would be in Java.

Comment: For anybody reading this now, I'd suggest using the task API to write the 3k entries in the background after a single file upload.